# React onClick element: call another class elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve a modal popup(which is stored in postview class) to appear when a onclick is called in any post on postcontainer class. I am new to react, so I would love your suggestion on improving code.

Class 1 (PostCointainer)
This is main class which shows multiple post from an array. I want the modal to appear from class 2 when any post is clicked

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import PostView from './PostView';
function RenderPost({posts}) {
    return (
     <div className="post-holder shadow-sm p-3 mb-4 bg-white rounded" key={posts.id} onClick={class postview class 2}>

    </div>
    );
}

const PostContainer = props => {

    const menu = props.posts.map(post => {
        return (
                <RenderPost posts={post} />
        )
    });

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <PostView />
               {menu}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PostContainer;
```

Class 2 (post View)

```
class PostView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isModalOpen : true,

        }
        this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
    }

    toggleModal(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        this.setState({
          isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
    <div className="shadow-sm p-2 mb-2 bg-white">
        <div 
           className="modal"
           style={{display: this.state.isModalOpen ? 'block' : 'none' }} 
           onClick={this.toggleModal} >
            <div 
               className="modal-content" 
               onClick={ e => e.stopPropagation() }  >
               <span 
                   className="close"
                   onClick={this.toggleModal}
                >&times;
               </span>
            <div className="container">
                <h3 className="form-header">Hello</h3>

              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
        );
    }
}
export default PostView;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply acheived by maintaining a state variabe for post click in the parent component and passing it via prop to child.

### PostContainer.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import PostView from './PostView';


const PostContainer = props => {
    const [post, setPost] = useState(false);

  function RenderPost({posts}) {
    return (
     <div className="post-holder shadow-sm p-3 mb-4 bg-white rounded" key={posts.id} onClick={setPost(posts)}>

    </div>
    );
  }


   const menu = props.posts.map(post => {
        return (
                <RenderPost posts={post} />
        )
    });

    return (
         <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <PostView post={post} />
               {menu}
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}

export default PostContainer;
```

### Constructor function of PostView Component

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isModalOpen : !!props.post,
    }
    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
}
```

And you can use the same post prop to render post in render function of your child component.
Hope it helps!!

Comment: the state is inside separate const and RenderPost is outside the cont, any way to pass the state as a parameter from const to function

Comment: @JRS you already have access to individual posts via the posts argument in renderPost function, we are then updating the post state using the setPost hook on every click to post which forces the modal to appear.

Comment: @amavpanwar99 please check the code in the [link](https://transfer.sh/15IAJw/PostContainer.js) 
how to call setPost inside RenderPost function -> return -> div in the above code link provided.
Thanks for you help